# Is the quotient morphism from product of curves to to their symmetric product flat?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Suppose $C$ is a smooth curve, is the morphism $C^2=C\times C\to C^{(2)}=C\times C/S_2$ flat? What about the general case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the canonical morphism $p: C^n\to C^{(n)}$ is flat by *miracle flatness*.

More precisely that aptly named theorem states that a morphism $p:X\to Y$  of varieties over a field is flat whenever $X$ and $Y$ are regular and all the fibers of $p$ have dimension $\dim X-\dim Y$ ($=0$ in our case).
For a proof of *miracle flatness* see [Matsumura, 23.1, page 179](http://ebooks.cambridge.org/ebook.jsf?bid=CBO9781139171762), where the result is proved under the weaker hypothesis that $X$ is only Cohen-Macaulay.